# Fill in values between given indices of 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array,

```
a = np.zeros((10,10))

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

And for a set of indices, e.g.:

```
start = [0,1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,0]
end   = [9,8,7,6,5,5,6,7,8,9]
```

how do you get the "select" all the values/range between the start and end index and get the following:

```
result = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
          [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

My goal is to 'select' the all the values between the each given indices of the columns.

I know that using `apply_along_axis` can do the trick, but is there a better or more elegant solution?

Any inputs are welcomed!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
r = np.arange(10)[:,None]
out = ((start  <= r) & (r <= end)).astype(int)
```

This would create an array of shape `(10,len(start)`. Thus, if you need to actually fill some already initialized array `filled_arr`, do -

```
m,n = out.shape
filled_arr[:m,:n] = out
```

Sample run -

```
In [325]: start = [0,1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,0]
     ...: end   = [9,8,7,6,5,5,6,7,8,9]
     ...: 

In [326]: r = np.arange(10)[:,None]

In [327]: ((start  <= r) & (r <= end)).astype(int)
Out[327]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

If you meant to use this as a mask with `1s` as the `True` ones, skip the conversion to `int`. Thus, `(start  <= r) & (r <= end)` would be the mask.

Comment: Given an arbitrary ndarray of shape (10,10) how would you use this to *select* the desired items/elements?

Comment: @wwii Well the `output ncols = len(start)` and `output nrows` user has to specify. But for a "squeezed in" version, it would be `end.max()+1`. I have kept it as `np.arange(10)[:,None]` with `10` being the no. of rows. But yes,  in a generic sense, we would need to initialize and assign with those number of rows and cols as the slice ends along each axis.

Comment: @wwii On that term, "select", I think OP meant "select  and assign". But again, OP could have meant to use the 1s as a selection mask to select from some other array. That's a possible way to interpret as well.

Comment: @Divakar Yup, i intended to use it as a mask

Comment: @snowflake Do you intend to use it as a mask to select elements off  some other array?

Comment: @Divakar Well, actually, i am trying to sum all values between the indices for every column. But using a mask a[mask].sum(axis=0) resulted in an error! So, i'm still thinking of another way to solve this!

Comment: @snowflake Do `(a*mask).sum(0)` or `np.einsum('ij,ij->j',a,mask)`.