# Pandas: Mark values between flags from another column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

The workflow is as below:

1. Groupby LineNum then
2. Mark values in LWS column greater than 50 as 'start'
3. Mark values in Text column containing ':'(colon) as 'end'
4. Mark values between start and end as 1 in 'ExpectedFlag'

**I have finished upto step 3 i.e upto column named 'end'**

I am not able to figure out how to mark values between start and end as in ExpectedFlag. Is there any way to mark this using pandas operation?

```
        text  LWS LineNum   start   end     ExpectedFlag
0   somethin    3       2       0     0                0
1   somethin    3       2       0     0                0
2   somethin    2       2       0     0                0
3   value      70       2       1     0                1
4   value       3       2       0     0                1
5   value:      3       2       0     1                1
6   val1      200       3       1     0                1
7   val1:       3       3       0     1                1
8   val2        3       3       0     0                0
9   val2      100       3       1     0                1
10  val2:       3       3       0     1                1
11  djsal       3       3       0     0                0
12  jdsal       3       3       0     0                0
13  ajsd        3       3       0     0                0
```

Comment: Please don't use pictures in your question.

Comment: Its actually the data itself. Expected output is embedded as a column in the data.

Comment: Exactly, post the data as *text*, not as an image

Comment: How do I put excel data as text, it'll be jumbled

Comment: Is it guaranteed that starts and ends are always paired? If not, and say you only had a start value, would you just want to fill everything after that start within each group?

Comment: @ALollz Exactly. You're right. I forgot to mention that. If only start is present, then fill everything after it.

Comment: @Alex I have posted it as data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding filling values between `start` and `end`, this can be done as follows, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118710/fill-in-values-between-given-indices-of-2d-numpy-array):

Data:

`df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[1,0],[0,0],[0,1],[0,0],[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[1,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,1],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],],columns=['start','end'])`

```
   start end
0   0   0
1   0   0
2   0   0
3   1   0
4   0   0
5   0   1
6   0   0
7   0   0
8   1   0
9   0   1
10  0   0
```

Take indices of `start` and `end`:

```
s = df.start.nonzero()[0]
e = df.end.nonzero()[0]
>>> s, e
(array([3, 8], dtype=int64), array([5, 9], dtype=int64))
```

Reshape original index:

```
>>> index = df.index.values.reshape(-1,1)

array([[ 0],
   [ 1],
   [ 2],
   [ 3],
   [ 4],
   [ 5],
   [ 6],
   [ 7],
   [ 8],
   [ 9],
   [10]], dtype=int64)
```

Then we can utilize numpy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
>>> index < [1]       >>> index < [1,2,3,4,5]
array([[ True],       array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False],             [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False],             [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False],             [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False],             [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False],             [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False],             [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False],             [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False],             [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False],             [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False]])            [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

For each `start`-`end` pair generate a condition:

```
>>> ((s <= index) & (index <= e))

array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

And then use `sum`:

```
 df['Expected Flag'] = ((s <= index) & (index <= e)).sum(axis=1)

    start  end  Expected Flag
0       0    0              0
1       0    0              0
2       0    0              0
3       1    0              1
4       0    0              1
5       0    1              1
6       0    0              0
7       0    0              0
8       1    0              1
9       0    1              1
10      0    0              0
```

One-liner:
`((df.start.nonzero()[0] <= df.index.values.reshape(-1,1)) & (df.index.values.reshape(-1,1) <= df.end.nonzero()[0])).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: Could you explain the reshape part of the solution better?

Comment: It just transforms index from `[1,2,3...]` to `[[1],[2],[3],...]`

Comment: This is a great solution. But could this be done without using index. I want to preserve my index and don't wanna use reset_index too. Is there any other way? Thank you.

Comment: Your index does not change, we use its transformed copy in the calculation.

Comment: My bad, didn't realize it was a copy. I tried your code. It works flawlessly. Logic in this is very unique though. Thanks for such an awesome answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can write and apply a function to do this:

```
def proc():
    started = False
    def inner(b):
        nonlocal started
        if started:
            if b == 1:
                started = False
            return 1
        else:
            if b == 1:
                started = True
                return 1
            return 0
    return inner

df['ExpectedFlag'] = (df['start'] + df['end']).apply(proc())
df
```

returns

```
        text  LWS  LineNum  start  end  ExpectedFlag
0   somethin    3        2      0    0             0
1   somethin    3        2      0    0             0
2   somethin    2        2      0    0             0
3      value   70        2      1    0             1
4      value    3        2      0    0             1
5     value:    3        2      0    1             1
6       val1  200        3      1    0             1
7      val1:    3        3      0    1             1
8       val2    3        3      0    0             0
9       val2  100        3      1    0             1
10     val2:    3        3      0    1             1
11     djsal    3        3      0    0             0
12     jdsal    3        3      0    0             0
13      ajsd    3        3      0    0             0
```