# How to transform rectangle bounds to array slice in a vectorized manner?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to fill N rectangle-shaped regions of an 0-filled two dimensional array with ones. Regions to fill are stored in Nx4 numpy array, where each row contains rectangle bounds (x_low, x_high, y_low, y_high). This part is currently the slowest part of what I'm currently working, and I'm wondering if it can be done any faster.

Currently this is done by simply iterating over region array, and target array is filled with ones using slices:

```py
import numpy as np
def fill_array_with_ones(coordinates_array, target_array):
    for row in coordinates_array:
        target_array[row[0]:row[1], row[2]:row[3]] = 1

coords = np.array([[1,3,1,3], [3,5,3,5]])
target = np.zeros((5,5))
fill_array_with_ones(coords, target)
print(target)
```

Output:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

I was expecting that there is some numpy magic that would allow me to do it in a vectorized manner, which would get rid of iterating over rows and, hopefully, lead to faster execution:

```py
target[bounds_to_slices(coords)] = 1
```

Comment: This should help out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118710/fill-in-values-between-given-indices-of-2d-numpy-array

Comment: @Divakar Interesting approach. However, here it gets a bit more complicated as we have to repeat this procedure for both axes:
`x_mask = ((x_start  <= rows) & (rows < x_end));
y_mask = ((y_start  <= cols) & (cols < y_end))    
`
The masks here contain information if ith row is contained in jth rectangle. While this operation is quick indeed, in order to get final result we have to `np.matmul` those masks, and this gets quite slow when matrices are bigger. Correct me if I got something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I did some test about the method mentioned in comment and the `for` loop method. I'm wondering is your bottle neck really this?

```
# prepare data
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((1024, 1024), '?')
bound = np.random.randint(0, 1024, (9999,4), 'H')

# build indices, as indices can be pre-computed, don't time it
x = np.arange(1024, dtype='H')[:,None]
y = x[:,None]

# the force vectorized method
%%timeit
ymask = y >= bound[:,0]
ymask &= y < bound[:,1]
xmask = x >= bound[:,2]
xmask &= x < bound[:,3]
a[(ymask & xmask).any(2)] = True
# outputs 3.06 s ± 1.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# the normal method
%%timeit
for i,j,k,l in bound:
    a[i:k,j:l] = True
# outputs 22.8 ms ± 28.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Not only the "vectorized" method is always slower no matter how many bounding boxes are there, it also generates a 10GB temp array here. On the other hand the normal method is reasonably fast.

Comment: Since the `and`-`any` procedure is basically generalized matrix multiplication, you can try `np.matmul` to save space (haven't tested), but at least I found it's even slower

Comment: Yup, `np.matmul` makes this much slower for bigger matrices. Normal method has the advantage of being independent of target array size. 
By bottleneck I meant that this part is the slowest part of the whole process I'm implementing - that's why I wanted to shave off some milliseconds of it.